# Why can't I see my existing albums in the Facebook Exporter for iPhoto plugin?

Tags: macos, mac, iphoto, facebook

So I've installed the Facebook Exporter for iPhoto plugin. In iPhoto, when I select some pictures and click on "Export..." in the "Share" menu, I have a new tab "Facebook" now.

After I click the "Log in" button on that tab and log into Facebook in the browser that pops up, the plugin sais I'm logged in, but the combobox containing the "existing albums" only contains "Facebook Exporter for iPhoto Photos" even though there are several albums on my profile. Even albums that I've created previously using this plugin. There's also the text "No albums found" right under the combobox.

I tried exposing some albums to "Everyone" in stead of only to "Friends and Networks", but that didn't change the situation.

I would really like to add some pictures to existing albums. What am I missing here? Why can't the plugin see my existing albums?

Comment: You could try the new version of iPhoto, I think it has facebook integration built-in.

Comment: @Daniel: I know, problem is, I have a very old iBook G4 and don't want to spend any more money on it. Also it is already very slow, so upgrading to an even more feature-full version of iPhoto might make it even slower.

Comment: Understandable. Depending on local law, you might be able to sell it off via eBay/craigslist/Amazon Market Place after you got a shiny new machine though. Regarding performance, they probably have a trial version. You could backup your data (because upgrades might render your library unusable for older software versions) and try it. Some Apple software has actually become faster (or at least not slower) over the years, you might be lucky.